# How do I find the probability of getting an average when selecting from a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

If I have that scores follow a normal distribution, I know that the probability of selecting any person at random and them getting a score between 1 and 2 sd's above the mean is 13.6%. If I randomly select 4 people what is the probability that their scores will average to a value between 1 and 2 sd's above the mean? I dont care where any of their individual scores are only that they average to a value between 1 and 2 sds above the mean.

Comment: You have to use the sampling distribution of the means and the central limit theorem to find out that the standard distribution of the mean will narrowed when you take a sample by a factor of $1\sqrt{n}=1/2.$ Then you just have to go to the tables, or any software, to find out that the probability is close to $2.3\%$.

Comment: Saying the same thing another way: the sum of independent normal random variables is another normal random variable whose variance is the sum of the variances of the original variables. Here, the sum of four independent normal random variables with the same variance will be a normal random variable with four times the variance, so that its standard deviation is twice as large as before. This allows you to calculate your answer, once you replace the mean being between 1 and 2 (original) sds high with their sum being 4 to 8 (original) sds high.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate The central limit theorem is absolutely not necessary, since under the given conditions the mean is already normally distributed. The remaining part is correct.

Comment: @trancelocation It makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $\bar X =\frac 14(X_1 + \cdots + X_4)$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Under the given conditions we have

$$\bar X \sim N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{4}\right)$$

Hence,

$$P(\sigma \leq \bar X - \mu \leq 2\sigma ) = P\left(2\leq \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{2}}\leq 4\right)=\Phi(4)-\Phi(2)$$

where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Simulation:** $n = 4,  \mu = 68,  \sigma = 4.$
Perhaps normally distributed heights in inches of four students.

```
set.seed(217)
n = 4;  mu = 68;  sg=4
a = replicate(10^6, mean(rnorm(n,mu,sg))) # 10^6 sample averages
mean((a > mu+sg) & (a < mu+2*sg))
[1] 0.022626
2*sd((a > mu+sg) & (a <= mu+2*sg))/1000
[1] 0.0002974161  # aprx 95% margin of simulation error
```

With a million iterations, one can expect about three place
accuracy, so this result is in essential agreement with @trancelocation's result (+1) $\Phi(4) = \Phi(2) = 0.023.$

```
pnorm(4)-pnorm(2)
[1] 0.02271846
```

Because the average of four $A = \bar X_4 \sim
\mathsf{Norm}(68, 2)$ we can get the same numerical
result directly (without standardizing) in R:

```
diff(pnorm(c(72,76), mu, sg/2))
[1] 0.02271846
```

The histogram below shows simulated values of $A$ along
with its normal distribution (solid orange curve). Vertical dashed lines
mark the interval $(\mu + \sigma, \mu + 2\sigma) = (72, 76).$ The dotted density curve of $\mathsf{Norm}(68, 4)$  is for each *individual* observation.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "n=4: Dist'n of Sample Means"
hist(a, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", xlim=c(55,80), main=hdr)
 abline(v = c(mu+sg, mu+2*sg), lwd=2, col="darkgreen", lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg/sqrt(n)), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(v = c(mu+sg, mu+2*sg), lwd=2, col="darkgreen", lty="dashed")
```